# To wrap Legend Text in Zedgraphs

Tags: zedgraph

Is there any way to wrap a legend text in Zedgraphs.

In my application the legend text are lengther, this makes graph look small. So i need a way to wrap legend text in order to maintain the uniformity of graph size.

Thanks
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no automated way to do this, so you probably have to insert line breaks `\n` yourself. Like this, for example:

```
zgc.GraphPane.AddCurve("curve with a\nterribly long\nname that\ncould potentially\nstretch far\nacross the pane", 
    new[] { -0.3, 0.5, 0.9 }, new[] { 0.8, 0.3, 0.1 }, Color.Blue);
```

This will cause the text to display line-wrapped, but unfortunately the width of the legend line and symbol is also determined by the length of the curve name and becomes unnecessarily extended. To avoid this issue you additionally need to disable the display of lines and symbols in your legend:

```
zgc.GraphPane.Legend.IsShowLegendSymbols = false;
```

End result would then look something like this:

[image: Long curve name in legend]